# Why is "redise" used here?

Tags: sens, subjonctif, mode-grammatical

> À ma mère
>   et que ce petit Patachou que je lui amène en
>   le tenant par la main
>   lui redise avec gratitude tout bonheur
>   de mon enfance

This is from *Patachou, petit garçon*  by  Tristan Derème

Is the meaning as follows?

"To my mother
and to small Patachou whom I took  by the hand
and told  much about my happy boyhood with pleasure."

I do not understand  why the author used the word  "redise"="redire".

Comment: *redise* is the subjunctive of *redire*
Que ce petit patachou * redise avec gratitude tout bonheur de mon enfance

*(que je lui amène en le tenant par la main)

Comment: @Archa You should make it an answer and tell them on the way why subjenctive is needed here.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an article:

> *À ma mère et que ce petit Patachou que je lui amène en le tenant par la main lui redise avec gratitude tout **le** bonheur de mon enfance*

*Redise* is a conjugated form of *redire* (repeat, reiterate, tell again), here at the third person of the subjunctive present because it is a wish.

Here is one way to translate that dedication:

> To my mother; and may this small Patachou, whom I bring to her holding him by the hand, reiterate with gratitude all the happiness of my boyhood.

Comment: Gratitude, plutôt ! Je ne sais pas comment éditer pour une simple coquille. (le Urban Dictionnary donne, pour gratitute : "a fart that you are grateful for").

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues c'est normal, si tu n'as pas assez de réputation, tu ne peux que "proposer" une édition, et il faut modifier plus de 5 caractères il me semble. Plus tard, tu pourras éditer sans approbation, peu importe le nombre de caractères ;)

Answer (score 3):

The word *redise* is a form of the verb *redire* (subjunctive present). *Redire* follows a systematic construction: the prefix *re-* meaning “to do something again”, plus the verb *dire* meaning “say, tell”.

The construction in this sentence is rather difficult... The key word is the first *que*, and it's drowned in the mass of words. Let's start simple:

> Que Patachou fasse quelque chose.

The word *que* has many different types of usage. With most of them, *que* starts a complement of a preceding verb or noun. Here, *que* starts a standalone sentence. *Que* follows by a verb in the subjunctive mood expresses an order or a wish. Here, it's a wish: the speaker wishes that Patachou does something.

Now let's add the part that says what Patachou is supposed to do:

> Que Patachou lui redise tout le bonheur de mon enfance.

i.e. literally may Patachou tell her again about all the happiness of the speaker's childhood. Here the verb *dire* is not about saying a specific thing, but about conveying an idea, a feeling. Think “tell the tale of” rather than “tell” in English — “May Patachou tell her again the tale of the happiness of my childhood.”

Now we add complements: add more qualifiers about *Patachou*, and add “*avec gratitude*” to qualify *redire*. Here's the sentence with key syntactic groups marked:

> Que {ce petit Patachou {que je lui amène {en le tenant par la main}}} lui redise {avec gratitude} {tout le bonheur de mon enfance}.

Finally “*À ma mère*” ((dedicated) to my mother) and that sentence are joined together with *et*.

Answer (score 2):

**Addendum to the previous answers**

Prefix *"re"* is very common in French (for a verb) and it indicates that the action was repeated. Some verbs with *"re"* have entered the dictionary but you can also create your own verbs, even with multiple *"re"*, and everyone should understand.

The common prefix is *"re"* (pronounced "reuh") but it you add it before a verb beginning with the sound "é" (or "è"), *"re"* is pronounced "ré". Example (note that I am a chemist):

> J'ai extrait une première fois avec XXX mais ça n'a pas marché. J'ai tout **ré-extrait** avec YYY ; encore un échec. Du coup, j'ai **ré-ré-extrait** avec du ZZZ et ça a finalement marché.

Answer (score 1):

Redise is the subjunctive of redire. And the tense is past subjunctive, not past perfect.

So the sentence would* translate:

> "To my mother and to small Patachou whom I took by the hand and *would re-tell* much about my happy boyhood with pleasure."

*Note the use of the subjunctive, would, here, as well.